# How to implement this layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a web page which shows only 3 events in a grid and when the screen is re-sized less a certain width, it not only relocates the 3 events into a list but also changes the layout inside each event.

I have tried many ways to make it look like that web page, but have not got any luck.

this is the [web page](https://www.nike.com/events-registration/series?id=1480&days=0)

And this is what I have done:  [CodePen](http://codepen.io/franva/pen/raEaYM?editors=110)

```css
/* -- DEFAULTS -- */
div, ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* -- FLUID GRID STYLES -- */
#Grid {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0.1px;
}

#Grid li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  width: 23%;
  padding-top: 23%;
  /* Used instead of height to give elements fluid, width-based height */
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

#Grid:after {
  content: 'haha';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 10px dashed #922d8d;
  /* Border added to make element visible for demonstration purposes */
}

ul li .icon {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #545454 url(https://www.nike.com/events-registration/client-dist/assets/images/multi-card-bg.png) no-repeat center center;
}

#Grid .placeholder {
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid #922d8d;
  /* Border added to make element visible for demonstration purposes */
}

/* -- MEDIA QUERIES DEFINING RESPONSIVE LAYOUTS -- */

/* 3 COL */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #Grid li {
    width: 31%;
    padding-top: 31%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
}

/* 2 COL */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #Grid li {
    width: 48%;
    padding-top: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
}

/* SINGLE COL */
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #Grid li {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
}

/* -- LEGEND STYLES (NOT PART OF GRID FRAMEWORK) -- */
h1 {
  font: 600 20px"Helvetica Neue";
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

label {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  font: 100 22px"Helvetica Neue";
  border-left: 10px solid #922d8d;
}

label:last-of-type {
  border-left: 10px dotted #922d8d;
}

p {
  font: 200 15px/1.5em"Helvetica Neue";
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #333;
}
```

---

**Update**

Here is my [updated code](http://plnkr.co/edit/9LoD1fDxFyJZJq2lM1IR?p=preview). The problem is I cannot place the "1 JAN" and "NEW YEAR" in the middle of the div.

**Updat 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

          <div class="row hidden-xs icon">
            <div class="title">1 JAN</div>
            <div class="event-time"><i>8:00PM</i></div>
            <div class="sub-title">This Event is Full</div>
          </div>


          <div class="row hidden-xs sub-icon">
            <div><span>LRC Thursday Night Run test long long</span></div>
            <div>
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />  
            </div>

          </div>


          <div class="row hidden-sm event-sm">
            <div class="col-xs-4 event-left">
              <div class="event-day">01</div>
              <div class="event-month">JAN</div>
              <div class="event-time"><i>8:00PM</i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 event-right">
              <div class="event-notice">This event is full</div>
              <div class="event-title">NIKE RUN 10 KM</div>
              <div class="event-slogan">Come run with us</div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          <h1 class="text-center hidden-xs">14 FEB</h1>
          <p class="text-center hidden-xs">Valentine</p>
          <div class="row hidden-sm">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><i>February 14th</i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">Ah! Lovey Dovey Day... Where is my chocolate?</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          <h1 class="text-center hidden-xs">1 APR</h1>
          <p class="text-center hidden-xs">April Fool</p>
          <div class="row hidden-sm">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><i>April 1st</i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">Your car just got stolen.... JUST KIDDING!!!</div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Comment: You could look at Bootstrap?

Comment: hi @Lee it does have to use Bootstrap.

Comment: Okay.. then use it.. The column grid layout will be ideal for this kind of thing

Comment: read up on how `css media queries` work

Comment: @Lee other than the Bootstrap, there are more details which need to be done in order to implement the effect.

Comment: Maybe, but its a very good start to use, and will certainly utilise the ordering and layout better than your CodePen example.

Comment: hi @charlietfl I do have mediaquery in my css.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: hi @Rob I have added in my code. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using Bootstrap, you already have this capability.  Use hidden-.. and the col-xx-... classes to make your page responsive.

See this example: http://embed.plnkr.co/IH4WeZ/

It's all done using bootstrap css.  The trick is to hide stuffs at certain media query and show them whenever appropriate.

I only coded it be responsive at small and extra small size, so on medium and large it's a bit bonker... but you get the idea...

Comment: Fantastic~!!! "hidden-sm" that's why after re-sized some elements went disappeared!!! Thank you! I will start to tweak base on your code! Now I really want to put the Image part in it.

Comment: You might want to start looking at either `display:table-cell` or flex layout.  example: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: If  you are going to post example code, you should do it here, within your answer, and not a third party site. Links go dead (and I help close questions and answers with this problem almost every day).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Bootstrap grid system to do something like this.

You could use a combination of the columns, and offset to achieve this.

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

That will span three columns across the full width of the page. You could experiment with smaller width columns, and adding an offset to the first one to push it away from the left edge.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve a similar effect, try and replicate it with minimal code and work from there.

Here is a simple example I have knocked up to get the layout working:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPeXgj

**HTML**

```
<ul class="events">
  <li>Event Name</li>
  <li>Event Name</li>
  <li>Event Name</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.events {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.events li {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  .events li {
    width: 33.3%;
    clear: none;
  }

}
```

Using a mobile first approach, child items are styled with a `width: 100%;` and `clear: both;` Then, with a simple media query, I float them left and set a width to around a 3rd (33.3%) (there could be a better way, but this was a quick fix).

If you're using a grid system, it may be even easier. I would look into Bootstrap or Foundation, as many of these problems have already been solved many times over.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Michael, inside each of the even, it has a picture on the top and the description part at the bottom. And when resized to smaller screen, some parts will go disappear. And the upper / down parts become left/right parts. So this is what I really want to know.

Answer (score -3):

Last resort solution is to code two versions. One for mobile and another one for desktop. Then use media queries to hide one on mobile resolution and the other on desktop. 
This will add some extra load on the page, but it should do it.

Comment: And why is this not correct?  That's basically what Nike is doing unless they are doing some other crazy stuffs to move things around to get the content right at different size... confused.